# Foreign key in main table or supplementary table?

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-design

I have two tables with one to one relationship b/w student and Student_detail(kind of supplementary table) table

Design 1

```
Student
 student_id
 name
 ....
```

Student_detail

```
 student_detail_id
  student_id(foreign key to student_id in student table)
  ...
```

Design 2

```
Student
 student_id
 name
 student_detail_id (foreign key to student_detail_id in Student_detail table)
 ....
```

Student_detail

```
 student_detail_id
   ...
```

My question is which approach is better ? From design perspective is it better to keep the foreign key in main table(in this case student table) or
in supplementary table (student_detail table ) ?

Per my understanding approach 2 is better as if we add more supplementary tables we don't have to modify main table ?

Comment: If the tables are 1:1, why have two tables??  (There are valid reasons, but I want to know your justification.)

Comment: As main table already has close to 100 columns. So it is partitioned into two . columns which are less frequently used are kept in supplimentary table. Also this is legacy design not newly introduced.

Comment: Even if a justifiable one-to-one, I'd still treat the "primary" table as if it were a parent, and the "detail" as if it were one _potentially_ multiple children.  Thus the FK would go in the 'details' table.  More appropriately named 'additional_student_details'.

Comment: @EdStevens - Put that in an Answer.

Comment: I think a student detail cannot exist without a student. So I'd put the FK in the student detail table as a `NOT NULL` to enforce that. As a student probably should only have one detail entry I'd also make it `UNIQUE` (or the PK).

Comment: @stickybit *I think a student detail cannot exist without a student.* I think a student without details must not exist too. If so we have a case of vertical sharding instead of simple 1:1 relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested that previous comment be posted as 'answer'.  Here 'tis.

Even if a justifiable one-to-one, I'd still treat the "primary" table as if it were a parent, and the "detail" as if it were one of  potentially multiple children. Thus the FK would go in the 'details' table. More appropriately named 'additional_student_details'.

Answer (score 1):

After reading couple of articles on google and comment here, I believe ideally there should not be any need for supplementary table.  But yes if there is any FK should go inside detail/supplementary  like one to many relationship. Also we don't have to modify main table in case any new further details table come up in future